# Change url in php after reloading a page

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-string

My home page url looks like this

```
http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/12
```

I have a link of language on home page when a user clicks on that link i am sending that language id as query string , the page reloads and the url converts to

```
http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/?bid=12&ln=2
```

I want to reload the page with the new language but don't want to change my url i-e I want my URL to be

```
http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/12
```

after the page loads

How it is possible please me some gud ideas
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a php framework?

Comment: @safarov yes i m using codeigniter

Comment: The link looks like this <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/box/?bid=12&ln=2"> where bid and ln are dynamic

Comment: Just set a language cookie. Then the language is not dictated by the URL. For example, when the user clicks the language link, `setcookie('ln', 2);` and when you get a page request you can check `$_COOKIE['ln']` for the language to use.

Comment: @DaveRandom Can u ply provide me some basic sudo code I m using codeigniter with a controller and view

Comment: I have both of these urls in 2 different variables is there any php function that can replace one url with another ?

Comment: Why would you not want http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/12 over http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/?bid=12&ln=2? Codeigniter url's are much better prettier and it's so easy to grab the individual pieces of the url the CI way.

Answer (score 1):

**VIEW**

```
<a href=<?php echo site_url('home?language=indonesian');?>>Indonesian language</a>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $language = $this->input->get('language');
        if($language){

            // Put your code here

            // Now u can set session
            $this->session->set_userdata('language', $language);
            redirect('home');
        }

        if($this->session->userdata('language'))
        {
            var_dump($this->session->userdata('language'));
        }
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }

}
```

Comment: The language is still shown in the url and if i redirect to home page the changes dont take place