# Change url after loading a view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change url in php after reloading a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807229/change-url-in-php-after-reloading-a-page)

I might be repeating my question but i am providing the exact scenario this time with my actual code Kindly be patient with me ...
My Home page URL is

```
http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/12
```

on my home page I have two links for languages when I click on any of the link the page reloads with the content in that specific language.

The link is inside a view (template/index) and looks like this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/box/?bid=<?php echo $template_data['box_id']?>&ln=<?php echo $lang['language_id']?>"></a>
```

So i am sending bid and ln as qurystring with the link

Now when I click on the link the content of the page changes according to the language selected but the url also changes to

```
http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/?bid=12&ln=2
```

What i want is that the content of the page changes but not the url or can I make the url looks like this after loading the page

```
http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/12/language_name
```

The method in my controller that loads the home page and change the content when a language link is clicked is as follows

```
    public function box() {
        $url = $this->pageURL();
        $id_from_url = explode('/', $url);

        if (isset($_GET['bid'])) {
            $id = $this->input->get('bid');
        }
        else{
            $id = $id_from_url[6];
        }
        $query = $this->db->get_where('mc_boxes', array('idmc_boxes' => $id));
        $row = $query->row();
            if (isset($_GET['bid'])) {
                $box_id = $this->input->get('bid');
            } 
            else {
                $box_id = $row->idmc_boxes;
            }
            $customer_id = $row->customers_idcustomers;
            if (isset($_GET['ln'])) {
                $language_id = $this->input->get('ln');
            }
            else {
                $language_id = $row->languages_idlanguages;
            }
            $template_id = $this->Home_model->getTemplateID($box_id);
            $data['template_data'] = $this->Home_model->getTemplateData($template_id);
            $data['variables_data'] = $this->Home_model->getVariables($customer_id, $language_id);
            $data['titles_data'] = $this->Home_model->getTitles($box_id,$language_id);
            $data['categories'] = $this->Home_model->getCategories($customer_id, $language_id);
            $data['languages'] = $this->Home_model->getLanguages($box_id);
            $this->load->view('template/index', $data);

    }
```

Any ideas please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Faryal - wouldn't it be better to edit your old question? `:)`

Comment: Why pass by GET? You could pass values straight into the controller by doing <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/box/<?php echo $template_data['box_id']?>/<?php echo $lang['language_id']?>"></a> Then reading this into your controller like; public function box($box_id, $ln) {...}

Comment: @ Rooneyl but when I load my home page for first time I dont have that ln variable Do i need to change my routes as well ?

Comment: @FaryalKhan, just give it a default value in the contoller. E.g. public function box($box_id, $ln=1) {...}

Comment: @Rooneyl Can I apss a variable from view o controller? please see my latest question for detail

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple arguments for controller functions. But multiple arguments must have default value.

```
public function box($id, $language = 'en') {
    echo "id: " . $id . " - lang: " . $language;
}
```

when your link http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/12/language_name

this will return,

```
id: 12 - lang: language_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options as to how to extract data from the URI. Here are just two.

1. Every segment after `box/` in the URI will be passed as an argument to the `box` method as [levye suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820833/421939).
2. Use the [URL class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) to get the information you need.

You should be OK with method 1. Once you get into [remapping](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping) and rewriting URLs then method 2 will sometimes be your salvation.

I suggest reading [this page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri) from the CI manual to help you better understand how to pass data to your controllers.

This might help you understand the magic.

Put `die(var_dump($this->uri->segment_array()));` as the first line in your controller and then access http://localhost/mediabox/home/box/this_is_argument_1/this_is_2/4/500/six/ from your browser. `$this->uri->segment(3);` will hold the string `this_is_argument_1`, `$this->uri->segment(5) == 4;` etc. Keep in mind that segment 1 is the name of the controller and 2 is the name of the method being called.

Also note that the URL Class is initialized automatically by codeigniter so there is no need to load it manually (nor do you need to `explode()` or anything like that).